# Forms authentication in MVC3: return 401 (unauthorized) instead of redirect if user tries to access resource they're not authorized to

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have a public facing MVC3 site using forms authentication.  Using forms authentication, if a user isn't authorized it sends a redirect to a login page.  I don't desire this behavior, and would instead like the server to respond with 401 unauthorized.  Is there a simple way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public class 401AuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private class Http401Result : ActionResult
    {
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            // Set the response code to 401.
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new Http401Result();
    }
}
```

You'll have to use this attribute instead of `[Authorize]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  It's still redirecting with status code 302.

Comment: @w.brian: And did you mark your actions with `[401Authorize]`?

Comment: I actually had to name it Authorize401Attribute, because class names can't start with a number.  But, I did annotate it with `[Authorize401]`, yes.

Comment: @w.brian: See my updated answer. I added `context.HttpContext.Response.End();`.

Comment: @LukLed Could you please help me to take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866994/mvc4-custom-authentication-solution thanks a lot !